Identify TV Scifi Cartoon show about after Meteor Impact
I remember a (from the style it looked French/Canadian like this

Not much details sharp corner, not the typical us/disney-style) scifi TV Cartoon about kind of where a Asteroid/Meteor impact disabled tech or at least caused some major restrictions.
The main base of the hero (capital city in that timeline) was in a Inca/Aztec city. Main character was I believe flying in a propeller airplane. Not sure about the civilization (didnt see much outside the storyline) in general, the character was fighting the villain and the final episode played in the future in a futuristic city and an old woman talking to a boy. I saw it maybe in the end of the 90s.
The name might be similar to the 2-name type as indiana jones,etc.
It was a one-season show with an ending.
Anybody Ideas which show it was?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

It is named "Chris Colorado".

Um, please don't change your question in order to adapt to the answer. Becaause adding that image of the exact searched TV show into your question, frankly makes it look like a stupid question.

You might also want to elaborate a little more in which ways this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
